# How to add auto-complete Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I would like to add custom auto-complete key bindings much like built-in:

*Example: `html+tab` auto-completes the Doctype Block.*

I tried adding html custom key binding: type `c + o + l + tab` to generate `<div class="col-">`

Preferences > Key Bindings > Default (OSX).sublime-keymap -- User

`{"keys": ["c+o+l+tab"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<div class=\"col-$0\">"}},`


However, two issues:

1. the new key binding overrides all other auto completes
2. the initial **col** or characters remains in front of the
   generated tag. `col<div class="col-">`

What is the correct way to add this type of key binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do something like this is to use either [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) or [completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html). Although there are some differences, generally speaking they both work the same way in the end, and which one you choose depends on how many such items you want to create and how complex you want them to be.

Using a snippet, you would select `Tools > Developer > New Snippet...` from the menu and fill out the snippet template, then save it as a `sublime-snippet` file in the location that Sublime defaults to (which is your `User` package).

For example, that might look like the following based on the example in your question:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<div class="col-$0">
]]></content>
    <description>Insert DIV with column class</description>
    <tabTrigger>col</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Snippets are XML formatted, and everything between `![CDATA[` and `]]` is inserted into the buffer (don't remove the `CDATA` even if you think you don't need it; Sublime will ignore the snippet if you do).

The `tabTrigger` specifies the text that you want to be the trigger for the snippet, the `scope` says what sort of files the snippet should trigger in, and the `description` will be displayed next to the snippet in the auto-completions panel.

In a snippet, the `tabTrigger`, `scope` and `description` are all optional. If you don't specify a `tabTrigger` you can only expand the snippet from the Command Palette or via the `insert_snippet` command (for example in a key binding). Without a `scope` the snippet applies everywhere, and without `description` it has no description in the panel.

If you have many such items that you want to add snippets for, you can also use completions instead. These are stored in JSON files with an extension of `sublime-completions` and should be saved in your `User` package (use `Preferences > Browse Packages...` if you don't know where that is.

An example of such a file would be:

```json
{
    "scope": "text.html",

    "completions": [
        { "trigger": "col\tInsert DIV with column class", "contents": "<div class=\"col-$0\">" },
    ]
}
```

In this format, the `trigger` is always the text to trigger and the description (still optional) is separated from the trigger by a `\t` character in the `trigger` key.

In completions you only specify the scope once at the top instead of every time, but there are some functional differences between completions and snippets.

1. There can only be one snippet per `sublime-snippet` file, but a `sublime-completions` file can contain many completions in a single file; the `completions` key is an array so you can place more than one completion in the same file.
2. Completions are JSON, so contents that are multi line or contain JSON specific characters such as a `"` character are harder to enter; completions are better for shorter sequences while snippets are better for more complex things.
3. When autocomplete triggers, if there is a `completion` and a `snippet` that could be autocompleted, `snipptets` always "win" and are inserted, whereas completions cycle. That means that for example in this particular example you need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice because `col` is also the name of a tag.
4. Snippets automatically appear in the command palette (when they apply) but completions do not. In the command palette, Snippets appear as commands like `Snippet: Something`, where `Something` is the `description` if it exists and the name of the file if it does not.

In either case, you can make the snippet/completion apply only in certain types of files by applying a `scope`; to determine the appropriate scope, position the cursor in a file at the appropriate place and select `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name...`; the more of the displayed scope you use the more specific it becomes. Generally just the top level such as `text.html` is all that's needed unless you're doing something special.

Comment: I apologize for the late comment. However, your reply was extremely helpful and I was able to, eventually, add the custom competitions.